# Why extjs button handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a window containing some button after clicking 'cancel' nothing happens.
I'm really confused what could I'm getting wrong:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.User.NewForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    width: 610,
    height: 380,
    y: 50,
    resizable: false,
    closable: true,
    draggable: false,
    title: 'new user',

    items: [{
        buttons: [{
                text: 'save',
                iconCls: 'form-save'
            },{
                text: 'cancel',
                iconCls: 'form-cancel',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.cancel     
            }]
    }],
    cancel: function() { alert('cancel'); }

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Lolo says, `this.cancel` is undefined at the time when you define your Form class.

The standard solution for this problem is to create `items` array inside `initComponent`:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.User.NewForm', {
    ...

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
            buttons: [{
                text: 'save',
                iconCls: 'form-save'
            },{
                text: 'cancel',
                iconCls: 'form-cancel',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.cancel     
            }]
        }];

        this.callParent();
    },

    cancel: function() { alert('cancel'); }

});
```

When `initComponent` is invoked `this` points to the instance of your Form as one would expect. In you code `this` pointed to the global `window` object which didn't contain the cancel function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define your window buttons this way

```
...
initComponent: function(){
this.buttons =  [
            {   text:'Close',
                handler: function(){
                    this.up('window').close(); //<--Notice "this" refers to the button
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Save',
                action: 'save',
                handler: this.save,
                scope: this
            }
        ]; //eo buttons
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }, //eo initComponent
    save: function(){ ... }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because this.cancel is undefined. See this code:

```
var that = this;
Ext.define('Myapp.view.User.NewForm', {

    items: [{
        buttons: [{
                text: 'save',
                iconCls: 'form-save'
            },{
                text: 'cancel',
                iconCls: 'form-cancel',
                scope: this, // that === this
                handler: this.cancel     
            }]
    }],
    cancel: function() { alert('cancel'); }
})
```

This passed to scope points to the same object as that variable. You must find other way to get reference to the parent control.
You may try: `handler: function(){ this.ownerCt.ownerCt.cancel.apply(this, arguments); }`, and remove `scope: this` line.